# Supabase storage getPulicURL doesn't show image

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I am trying to display an image in Supabase storage bucket on my react app.  I console log the public url and it is correct but the image wont show.  Also when I got to the public url the image downloads automatically rather than appearing in the browser.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const { data, error } = supabase
    .storage
    .from('images')
    .getPublicUrl(`kk2.tiff`)

    setImage(data.publicURL)
  
  }, [])
```

Comment: you will have to share the `setImage` method so we can see how the URL is used on the front end

Answer (score 1):

As written in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types#tiff_tagged_image_file_format),

> Browser compatibility: No browsers integrate support for TIFF; its value is as a download format

You should convert image to other format